# Correct usage of command with percent sign

Tags: git, batch-file

I want to use git command `git show -s --format=%h` in batch file, want to store the result in variable.

**This doesn't work:**

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('git show -s --format=%h') DO set commit=%%i
echo commit=%commit%
```

because with `echo on` the command it executes is:

```
FOR /F %i IN ('git show -s --format') DO set commit=%i
```

and output is:

```
commit=
```

**This method works, but seems odd solution:**

```
set hhh="=%%h"
FOR /F %%i IN ('git show -s --format%hhh%') DO set commit=%%i
```

because the command executes is:

```
FOR /F %i IN ('git show -s --format"=%h"') DO set commit=%i
```

and output is correct:

```
commit=6446e53
```

I guess it it related to how variables are referenced and used in batch file with percent sign.

**Is there a better solution, that will execute as it should: `git show -s --format=%h`?**

Comment: To use a literal percent symbol in a batch file you need to double the percent symbol. `FOR /F %%i IN ('git show -s --format=%%h') DO set commit=%%i`

Comment: double percent echos this command: `FOR /F %i IN ('git show -s --format %h') DO set commit=%i` and also shows error `fatal: ambiguous argument '%h': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`    So, not working.

Comment: Forgot that equals symbols need to be escaped as well when it is within a `FOR` command execution.  `--format^=%%h`

Comment: yes, this works `git show -s --format^=%%h` ! Thanks! well, it works and it seems like it executes command in valid format!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of how to escape characters in batch files: [Escape Characters - by Rob van der Woude](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)

In case the link goes down in the future:

| Character to be escaped | Escape Sequence | Remark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| % | %% |  |
| ^ | ^^ | May not always be required in doublequoted strings, but it won't hurt |
| & | ^& |  |
| < | ^< |  |
| > | ^> |  |
| | | ^| |  |
| ' | ^' | Required only in the FOR /F "subject" (i.e. between the parenthesis), unless backq is used |
| ` | ^` | Required only in the FOR /F "subject" (i.e. between the parenthesis), if backq is used |
| , | ^, | Required only in the FOR /F "subject" (i.e. between the parenthesis), even in doublequoted strings |
| ; | ^; |  |
| = | ^= |  |
| ( | ^( |  |
| ) | ^) |  |
| ! | ^^! | Required only when delayed variable expansion is active |
| " | "" | Required only inside the search pattern of FIND |
| \ | \\ | Required only inside the regex pattern of FINDSTR |
| [ | \[ |  |
| ] | \] |  |
| " | \" |  |
| . | \. |  |
| * | \* |  |
| ? | \? |  |

Comment: As always, it's a little bit more complex. Don't use caret escaping inside quotes, as they are not removed anymore. BUT if delayed expansion is enabled, an exclamation mark inside quotes is escaped with `"^!"` outside of quotes you need two `^^!`. And to escape carets, when delayed expansion is enabled it becomes a little bit more complex. It can be `^^` or `^^^` depending on the existence of an exclamation mark somewhere in the same line